# An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to get ruby on rails to set up on my mac running os x 10.10. I am trying to get a server running open source project kandan however I am getting an error when trying to bundle install on the eventmachine 1.0.3 gem. I'm not sure exactly what i'm looking at, can anyone help me fix this?

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using activesupport 3.2.21
Using builder 3.0.4
Using activemodel 3.2.21
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using journey 1.0.4
Using rack 1.4.5
Using rack-cache 1.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.2.3
Using actionpack 3.2.21
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 3.2.21
Using arel 3.0.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.42
Using activerecord 3.2.21
Using activeresource 3.2.21
Using addressable 2.3.6
Using awesome_print 1.2.0
Using json 1.8.1
Using mini_portile 0.5.3
Using nokogiri 1.6.1
Using uuidtools 2.1.4
Using aws-sdk 1.38.0
Using bcrypt 3.1.7
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using better_errors 1.1.0
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using sass 3.2.13
Using bootstrap-sass 3.1.1.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using bourbon 3.1.8
Using columnize 0.8.9
Using debugger-linecache 1.2.0
Using byebug 3.2.0
Using cancancan 1.9.2
Using xpath 2.0.0
Using capybara 2.4.4
Using hitimes 1.2.2
Using timers 4.0.1
Using celluloid 0.16.0
Using ffi 1.9.6
Using childprocess 0.5.5
Using climate_control 0.0.3
Using cliver 0.3.2
Using cocaine 0.5.4
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.0.2
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4
Using rdoc 3.12.2
Using railties 3.2.21
Using coffee-rails 3.2.2
Using cookiejar 0.3.2
Using rest-client 1.6.7
Using docile 1.1.3
Using simplecov-html 0.8.0
Using simplecov 0.8.2
Using tins 1.1.0
Using term-ansicolor 1.3.0
Using coveralls 0.7.0
Using daemons 1.1.9
Using database_cleaner 1.2.0
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.3
Using warden 1.2.3
Using devise 3.2.4
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using eco-source 1.1.0.rc.1
Using eco 1.0.0
Installing eventmachine 1.0.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150808-95277-1j9ketn.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling binder.cpp
compiling cmain.cpp
compiling ed.cpp
compiling em.cpp
em.cpp:827:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_thread_select'; did you mean 'rb_thread_fd_select'?
        return EmSelect (maxsocket+1, &fdreads, &fdwrites, &fderrors, &tv);
               ^~~~~~~~
               rb_thread_fd_select
./em.h:25:20: note: expanded from macro 'EmSelect'
  #define EmSelect rb_thread_select
                   ^
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:454:5: note: 'rb_thread_fd_select' declared here
int rb_thread_fd_select(int, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, struct timeval *);
    ^
em.cpp:827:32: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'rb_fdset_t *' with an rvalue of type 'fd_set *'
        return EmSelect (maxsocket+1, &fdreads, &fdwrites, &fderrors, &tv);
                                      ^~~~~~~~
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:454:42: note: passing argument to parameter here
int rb_thread_fd_select(int, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, struct timeval *);
                                         ^
em.cpp:946:6: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_thread_select'; did you mean 'rb_thread_fd_select'?
                                        EmSelect (0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
                                        ^~~~~~~~
                                        rb_thread_fd_select
./em.h:25:20: note: expanded from macro 'EmSelect'
  #define EmSelect rb_thread_select
                   ^
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:454:5: note: 'rb_thread_fd_select' declared here
int rb_thread_fd_select(int, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, struct timeval *);
    ^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [em.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/eventmachine-1.0.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: You need to update eventmachine to 1.0.4 in order to make it work with Ruby 2.2.0

Answer (score 7):

Eventmachine 1.0.3 isn't compatible with Ruby 2.2+, try to upgrade to newer versions.

**Reading CHANGELOG:** You should upgrade, at least, to 1.0.4: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#104-december-19-2014

> fix build on ruby 2.2 [#503]

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `eventmachine` and `ruby version >= 2.2`

Please update eventmachine in Gemfile to 1.0.4

in Gemfile

```
gem `eventmachine', '~>1.0.4'
```

For more info

https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/553

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue even with `eventmachine -v '1.0.4'`. I successfully resolved the issue with this.

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.4'  -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the issue gets fixed on removing the **Gemfile.lock** and then using *http* instead of *https* in the *source* of **Gemfile** and then rebuilding the **Gemfile.lock** using the command

#### **`bundle exec jekyll build`**

I made a [boilerplate **Gemfile**](https://gist.github.com/harsh98trivedi/472cb45b29bfa9f7c1916e514802393a#file-gemfile) on GitHub Gist, you can use that too.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was `xcode-select --install` and click yes to install