# "An error occurred while installing eventmachine" with version 1.0.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Can someone help me to solve this problem:

```
 An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.8), and Bundler cannot
    continue.
    Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

It comes after I do: "bundle install" in my environment.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.8'?

Comment: Also see [An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31880676/608639).

Answer (score 6):

Create a reference for the OpenSSl gem was the key. I did something like this:

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.8' -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

and finally worked for me.

Thanks @Jack and @Jww for his help.